# vb .NET custom control inheriting from TextBox doesn't fire Paint event

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I need a multiline TextBox which is always disabled, but it shouldn't paint itself in gray, but I want to keep its designer choosen color.

I previously had the same requirement with an always-black Label (no multiline) and so I inherited from Label like:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

   Public Class LabelDisabled
        Inherits Label

        Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
            Enabled = False
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
            ' always draw it black
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

That works fine. Now I want the same thing but with a multiline label, so I chose to inherit from TextBox:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class CustomControl1
    Inherits TextBox

    Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()
        'Paint never fires anyway
        'Enabled = False
    End Sub


    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        Dim brush As New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, brush, 0, 0)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now the Paint event is never fired in the CustomControl1 - TextBox inherited - control.

Why can't I get the Paint event?

Also, if I want to make the Enabled property invisible and not-settable by the user, I do:

```
<Browsable(False),
DefaultValue(False)>
Public Overloads Property Enabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
    End Set
End Property
```

But this way, neither I can set the "real" Enabled property, I mean the backing field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution. It looks like a TextBox disables the Paint event even for subclasses. But you can force the WM_PAINT bit calling SetStyle:

```
Public Class DisabledTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Enabled = False
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, False)
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
        Dim brush As New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, brush, 0, 0)
    End Sub

End Class
```

It works perfectly as expected :)

Comment: I still have some minor issues: my textbox is now disabled, non-selectable and pretty colored, but the wordwrapping is just bad. DrawString just truncates a word if it can't fit in the current line, and then continues to the next line (but the word's been truncated anyway). 

I'd like to use the wordwrapping feature of a TextBox with the colouring feature of my DisabledTextBox.

Ideas?

Comment: Looks like I am answering myself today :)
Replasce the DrawString with:

e.Graphics.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, brush, Me.ClientRectangle)

Having a rectangle instead of a Point, gives a good wordwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, Me.DisplayRectangle)
    Dim sf As New StringFormat
    sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap
    sf.HotkeyPrefix = Drawing.Text.HotkeyPrefix.Show 'if Mnemonic property is set to true
    sf.HotkeyPrefix = Drawing.Text.HotkeyPrefix.Hide 'or none if Mnemonic property is set to false
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center 'horizontal alignment
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center ' vertical ...
    Dim rect As Rectangle = Me.DisplayRectangle ' this is your text bounds for setting your text alignement using StringFormat(sf)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Something", Me.Font, Brushes.DarkOliveGreen, rect, sf)
End Sub
```

Comment: Add some comments, what does your answer adds to the OP self answer?