# Dynamically draw on top of controls in Winform C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, controls

I'm student in computer scientist. For a project, I want to draw lines dynamically on my Winform, The problem is that i can only draw on the winform and the controls in it hide my drawings like that:
[image]

So I've done a lot of researches, and found that [solution](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/dialog/graphicaloverlaycomponent.aspx). Pretty much every post I've found leads to this link. I've asked directly in commentary of the post but nobody seems interested in that anymore, so I've come here.

The solution works fine, but not in the way I want it to work. It draws my lines on top of the controls when the Form loads, but then it doesn't do anything more. I would like to refresh it as often as i can.

I've copied the code from the Code Project link above and changed it a bit to fit my needs, so here's what I've got so far: (as the function that draws my lines)

```
private void graphicalOverlay_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen myPen;
    myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 10);
    Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
    formGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
    formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, Arm_1.PointA.X, Arm_1.PointA.Y, Arm_1.PointB.X, Arm_1.PointB.Y);
    myPen.Color = Color.Blue;
    formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, Arm_2.PointA.X, Arm_2.PointA.Y, Arm_2.PointB.X, Arm_2.PointB.Y);


    Rectangle rect = this.ClientRectangle;
    rect.Inflate(-10, -10);

    Pen pen;

    pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, Arm_1.PointA.X, Arm_1.PointA.Y, Arm_1.PointB.X, Arm_1.PointB.Y);
    pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, Arm_2.PointA.X, Arm_2.PointA.Y, Arm_2.PointB.X, Arm_2.PointB.Y);

    pen.Dispose();
    e.Dispose();
    myPen.Dispose();
    formGraphics.Dispose();

}
```

And this being the graphicalOverlay control (directly copied from Code Project)

```
namespace CodeProject
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class GraphicalOverlay : Component
    {
        public event EventHandler<PaintEventArgs> Paint;
        private Form form;

        public GraphicalOverlay()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public GraphicalOverlay(IContainer container)
        {
            container.Add(this);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public Form Owner
        {
            get { return form; }
            set 
            {
                // The owner form cannot be set to null.
                if (value == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException();

                // The owner form can only be set once.
                if (form != null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();

                // Save the form for future reference.
                form = value;

                // Handle the form's Resize event.
                form.Resize += new EventHandler(Form_Resize);

                // Handle the Paint event for each of the controls in the form's hierarchy.
                ConnectPaintEventHandlers(form);
            }
        }

        private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form.Invalidate(true);
        }

        private void ConnectPaintEventHandlers(Control control)
        {
            // Connect the paint event handler for this control.
            // Remove the existing handler first (if one exists) and replace it.
            control.Paint -= new PaintEventHandler(Control_Paint);
            control.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Control_Paint);

            control.ControlAdded -= new ControlEventHandler(Control_ControlAdded);
            control.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(Control_ControlAdded);

            // Recurse the hierarchy.
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
                ConnectPaintEventHandlers(child);
        }

        private void Control_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            // Connect the paint event handler for the new control.
            ConnectPaintEventHandlers(e.Control);
        }

        private void Control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // As each control on the form is repainted, this handler is called.

            Control control = sender as Control;
            Point location;

            // Determine the location of the control's client area relative to the form's client area.
            if (control == form)
                // The form's client area is already form-relative.
                location = control.Location;
            else
            {
                // The control may be in a hierarchy, so convert to screen coordinates and then back to form coordinates.
                location = form.PointToClient(control.Parent.PointToScreen(control.Location));

                // If the control has a border shift the location of the control's client area.
                location += new Size((control.Width - control.ClientSize.Width) / 2, (control.Height - control.ClientSize.Height) / 2);
            }

            // Translate the location so that we can use form-relative coordinates to draw on the control.
            if (control != form)
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-location.X, -location.Y);

            // Fire a paint event.
            OnPaint(sender, e);
        }

        private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Fire a paint event.
            // The paint event will be handled in     Form1.graphicalOverlay1_Paint().

            if (Paint != null)
                Paint(sender, e);
        }
    }
    }

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    using System.Drawing;

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static Rectangle Coordinates(this Control control)
        {
            // Extend System.Windows.Forms.Control to have a Coordinates property.
            // The Coordinates property contains the control's form-relative location.
            Rectangle coordinates;
            Form form = (Form)control.TopLevelControl;

            if (control == form)
                coordinates = form.ClientRectangle;
            else
                coordinates = form.RectangleToClient(control.Parent.RectangleToScreen(control.Bounds));

            return coordinates;
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is that the function "graphicalOverlay_Paint" is only called once, at the launch of the program. Does anybody know how to call it otherwise?

I hope I've been specific. This is my first question on this forum, tell me if I've done something wrong. Also, English is not my mother tong, sorry for the mistakes.
I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot for reading, and have an amazing day!

Erwan

EDIT 1: All credits to RocketScientist from the Code Project link for the codes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried to call your `graphicalOverlay_Paint` from form's `OnPaint`?

Comment: Ok, i can try that, but what do i put as arguments when calling it? I need to provide '(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)' and i think i haven't really understood what those things are.

Comment: Try with `graphicalOverlay_Paint(this,e);`

Comment: So i've tried calling as you said, but this resolves nothing. (but thank you a lot  anyway!) 
After a little bit more of digging, it appears the function actually is called, but the part which draws on the controls doesn't work properly.

I've discovered (totally randomly) that the lines are refreshed in some controls (only the buttons) when i press tab. I assume it has to do with the focus of the controls.Sadly the picturbox doesn't have that property.

I'm gonna do a little bit more of debuging and let you know. If you ahve any other ideas or suggestions so far, i'd be glad to read it.

Comment: As you can see on https://www.codeproject.com/ the textbox is not beeing overdrawn. So it seems like textbox has another behaviour...

Comment: Looks like you had to go through a lot of pain, to make it work for textboxes...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378148/how-to-draw-on-top-of-a-textbox