# Accessing to control inside of usercontrol

Tags: vb.net

I am making an usercontrol with only one textbox so basically I expect that properties of textbox have to be applied to whole usercontrol.
That means (for example) that I would like from outside of usercontrol (in main program which contain those usercontrol) to get value of those (intern) textbox's selectionstart property.

But I can't find a way to do this except in creating a new public property of my UC.
I suppose that here should be some better way because textbox have many properties which may be needed to read (or maybe write) from main program and making another public property in UC for **every** internal property of textbox don't seems like "way to go" for me.

Any advice on how to get properties of internal control in UC from main program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may inherit your usercontrol from textbox control,liKe:

```
Class MyTextbox
      inherits TextBox
End class
```

and then try to override, overload and access the events and properties you want.

---

you can check the following links,
   1- For [textbox inheritance example](http://spac3crow.webs.com/apps/blog/show/3103662-extending-a-textbox-control-to-add-custom-properties-vb-net-2008)
   2- Answered Question in [Satckoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564273/vb-net-custom-control-inheriting-from-textbox-doesnt-fire-paint-event)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in .NET. Since my usercontrol is finished, where to put that?

Comment: what i understand from your question, you  have only a textbox in your usercontrol, so you do not need create a user control, all what you need is to let your created calss to inherit all the properties and events of the textbox, so let your class, in .vb and .designer.vb files,to inherit from your Textbox, as shown in the sample above, let say your class name is MyTextbox, just add the 'inherits textbox'. and this will work

Comment: Yes, only one textbox where I add some new functionality and I intend to use it instead of ordinary textbox. So, where to put that class? In user control, in main program or...?

Comment: Thank you strumpfy. I am migrating from VB6 so this is still too complicated for me. But I belive that is solution for my problem.

Comment: YEAH, GET IT!!! "If myUC_Name.IsSelectedAll Or myUC_Name.XTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0 Then"... Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

Will not a regular FindControl check solve this?

Comment: `FindControl` in Winforms?