# Handling an event of control which is inside of usercontrol

Tags: vb.net

Soon I asked for help to read properties of textbox which is inside usercontrol.
[Accessing to control inside of usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988186/accessing-to-control-inside-of-usercontrol)
As I have been suggested I make one very simple public class with name xTextBox and use it as textbox in my usercontrol. That work fine.

```
Public Class xTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
End Class
```

Now I can simply read a property on that xTextbox from main program which contain that usercontrol:

```
Dim s As Integer = myUserControl.xTextBox1.SelectionStart
```

But now is a problem that I can't get events of that Textbox in main program.
Maybe I can declare 'Shadows Event TextChanged...' etc, but I will need more events in different situations where usercontrol would be, and intentionally raising every of them don't look elegant in mean of practical programming.

How to get events of those xTextbox to main program?

Comment: Yes it is, this textbox is only one control which contain those usercontrol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the your new UserControl has only one control and Inherits TextBox, then you can just attach the events like normal, either with the Property Editor, or Manually with AddHandler. If things are more complicated than that I would probably create a panel and put your new TextBox's in it, then it will be a lot easier to access the events.

```
Public Class myUserControl
    Inherits TextBox

End Class


Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        AddHandler MyUserControl1.TextChanged, AddressOf MyUserControl_textChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyUserControl_textChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

Or if your UserControl has Multiple Custom TextBox's in it, you can create a Custom Event and fire that in a common TextChanged Event  on your UserControl and handle that in your Main Form.

```
Public Class UserControl1
    Public Event TextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub MyUserControl_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyUserControl1.TextChanged, MyUserControl2.TextChanged
        RaiseEvent TextChange(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
End Sub
    Private Sub UserControl11_TextChange(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.TextChange
        MsgBox(CType(sender, TextBox).Name, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Well, that way I can declare an shadows event inside my UC and raise Textchanged of usercontrol when textchanged happen on textbox. But that way I would nedd to do this for every event. That's why I'm searching for more "elegant" solution, if possible.

Comment: Does your usercontrol inherit textbox, if so you do not need to Shadow anything, the UserControl for all rights is a TextBox so it's TextChangedEvent will fire with the Text in the Textbox is changed

Comment: As I am new in .NET this is what I don't understand still. Can I inherit now this textbox with usercontrol which is already inherited with xTextbox? If I can please show me how that should look with a little code example.

Comment: What I am not sure of, does your UserControl **Inherit** TextBox or do you have a Custom TextBox **in** your UserControl, if so the second example I posted woul be better

Comment: Those second solution don't look nice. Textbox have about 60 different events and when we talk about usercontrol every event may be needed some time.

Comment: I think in VB6 was some technique to MAP events in usercontrol. All events of same type may be overlaped. Like changed, click, mouseUp etc. When you invoke changed on textbox changed is automatically raised on usercontrol. Such solution would be nice here.

Comment: You are not going to get a clean implementation if you plan on handling every event. You will be better of using a panel then adding your custom textbox's to the panel, that way you can handle every event. A usercontrol is designed to encapsulate the logic, you then either handle everything in the UserControl and raise a event to pass the results to your Main Form, or you pick and choose what you want to expose.

Comment: Ok, if I dont find better then I would do handlers for raising few most needed events.